# json.JSONException: No value for ProductList

Tags: android, json

Following  is the code to search from a list of items. However it gives json.JSONException: No value for ProductList error everytime and prints  "Unable to connect Server please try later".

myAsyncTask class from Search.java

```
 class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    JSONParser jParser;
    JSONArray productList;
    String url = new String();
    String textSearch;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){

        super.onPreExecute();
        productList = new JSONArray();
        jParser = new JSONParser();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setMessage("Searching....");
        pd.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        pd.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sText){

        url= "http://demo5657559.mockable.io/getitems"+sText[0];
        String returnResult = getProductList(url);
        this.textSearch = sText[0];
        return returnResult;


    }

    public String getProductList(String url){

        Product tempProduct = new Product();
        String matchFound = "N";
        Log.d("Tatheer", "productResults size - "+productResults.size());

        try{

            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            productList = json.getJSONArray("ProductList");

            for(int i = 0; i<productList.length();i++){

                tempProduct = new Product();

                JSONObject obj = productList.getJSONObject(i);


                tempProduct.setProductCode(obj.getString("ProductCode"));
                tempProduct.setProductName(obj.getString("ProductName"));
                tempProduct.setProductGrammage(obj.getString("ProductGrammage"));
                tempProduct.setProductBarcode(obj.getString("ProductBarcode"));
                tempProduct.setProductDivision(obj.getString("ProductCatCode"));
                tempProduct.setProductDepartment(obj.getString("ProductSubCode"));
                tempProduct.setProductMRP(obj.getString("ProductMRP"));
                tempProduct.setProductBBPrice(obj.getString("ProductBBPrice"));

                matchFound = "N";

                for (int j = 0; j < productResults.size();j++){

                    if (productResults.get(j).getProductCode().equals(tempProduct.getProductCode())){

                        matchFound = "Y";
                    }

                }

                if (matchFound == "N"){

                    productResults.add(tempProduct);

                }



            }

            Log.d("Tatheer", "productResults size - "+productResults.size());
            return ("OK");



        }

        catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            return ("Exception Caught");
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("Exception Caught")){

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to connect Server please try later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            pd.dismiss();

        }

        else {


            Log.d("Tatheer", "existing on PostExecute");
            filterProductArray(textSearch);
            searchResults.setAdapter(new SearchResultsAdapter(getActivity(), filteredProductResults));
            pd.dismiss();
        }

    }


}


}
```

Logcat:

```
03-22 09:50:56.624 5733-5764/? W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No                    value for ProductList
03-22 09:50:56.624 5733-5764/? W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
03-22 09:50:56.624 5733-5764/? W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584)
03-22 09:50:56.624 5733-5764/? W/System.err:     at com.zing.basket.Search$myAsyncTask.getProductList(Search.java:167)
03-22 09:50:56.624 5733-5764/? W/System.err:     at com.zing.basket.Search$myAsyncTask.doInBackground(Search.java:151)
03-22 09:50:56.624 5733-5764/? W/System.err:     at com.zing.basket.Search$myAsyncTask.doInBackground(Search.java:125)
03-22 09:50:56.624 5733-5764/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
03-22 09:50:56.625 5733-5764/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-22 09:50:56.625 5733-5764/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
03-22 09:50:56.625 5733-5764/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
03-22 09:50:56.625 5733-5764/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
03-22 09:50:56.625 5733-5764/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-22 09:50:56.741 5733-5748/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab3d3650
```

Json

```
{
"ProductList":[
{

"ProductCode":"1", 
"ProductName":"DALDA Cooking oil 1 LTR",
"ProductGrammage":"5g",
"ProductBarcode":"1234567891011",
"ProductCatCode":"EDIBLE GROCERY",
"ProductSubCode":"OIL/GHEE",
"ProductMRP":"100",
"ProductBBPrice": "120"

}
]}
```

Kindly help!

Comment: What is the value stands for sText[0] in _url= "http://demo5657559.mockable.io/getitems"+sText[0];_?

Comment: After this line 

         JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

Just try to log your response 

          Log.w("Json response " , json.toString());

See what you get and we will debug from there.

Comment: Check this line `String returnResult = getProductList(url);` . So that you make sure the result is valid .

Comment: @RageshRamesh doesnt print anything.  Log.d("Tatheer", "productResults size - "+productResults.size()); prints 0.

Comment: @ZahidulIslam what about it?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan Not yet

Comment: does the productlist is returned in the response ?

Comment: no thats the problem. i think something is wrong with json. not able to read the product list.

Answer (score 0):

url= "http://demo5657559.mockable.io/getitems"+sText[0];

I think you need a backslash in the URL.
Ask the API developer for the correct format for calling the web api and also try out url= "http://demo5657559.mockable.io/getitems/"+sText[0];

Notice the backslash added in the url.

If the url is not correct, you might get an endpoint not found error and JSONArray "ProductList" would not be present in the response.

Comment: What is the value of sText[0]?

Answer (score 0):

```
class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    JSONParser jParser;
    JSONArray productList;
    String url = new String();
    String textSearch;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    String sText[0]=null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){

        super.onPreExecute();
        productList = new JSONArray();
        jParser = new JSONParser();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setMessage("Searching....");
        pd.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        pd.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sText){
if(sText[0]!=null){
        url= "http://demo5657559.mockable.io/getitems"+sText[0];
        String returnResult = getProductList(url);
        this.textSearch = sText[0];
        return returnResult;
}else{
url= "http://demo5657559.mockable.io/getitems";
            String returnResult = getProductList(url);
            this.textSearch = sText[0];
            return returnResult;
}



    }

    public String getProductList(String url){

        Product tempProduct = new Product();
        String matchFound = "N";
        Log.d("Tatheer", "productResults size - "+productResults.size());

        try{

            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            productList = json.getJSONArray("ProductList");

            for(int i = 0; i<productList.length();i++){

                tempProduct = new Product();

                JSONObject obj = productList.getJSONObject(i);


                tempProduct.setProductCode(obj.getString("ProductCode"));
                tempProduct.setProductName(obj.getString("ProductName"));
                tempProduct.setProductGrammage(obj.getString("ProductGrammage"));
                tempProduct.setProductBarcode(obj.getString("ProductBarcode"));
                tempProduct.setProductDivision(obj.getString("ProductCatCode"));
                tempProduct.setProductDepartment(obj.getString("ProductSubCode"));
                tempProduct.setProductMRP(obj.getString("ProductMRP"));
                tempProduct.setProductBBPrice(obj.getString("ProductBBPrice"));

                matchFound = "N";

                for (int j = 0; j < productResults.size();j++){

                    if (productResults.get(j).getProductCode().equals(tempProduct.getProductCode())){

                        matchFound = "Y";
                    }

                }

                if (matchFound == "N"){

                    productResults.add(tempProduct);

                }



            }

            Log.d("Tatheer", "productResults size - "+productResults.size());
            return ("OK");



        }

        catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            return ("Exception Caught");
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("Exception Caught")){

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to connect Server please try later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            pd.dismiss();

        }

        else {


            Log.d("Tatheer", "existing on PostExecute");
            filterProductArray(textSearch);
            searchResults.setAdapter(new SearchResultsAdapter(getActivity(), filteredProductResults));
            pd.dismiss();
        }

    }


}


}
```

Comment: do in background i checked the condition if(sText[0]!=null){

Answer (score 0):

Fetch `JSON` using [HttpUrlConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) and then parse the string

**Example**

```
// Given a URL, establishes an HttpUrlConnection and retrieves
// the web page content as a InputStream, which it returns as
// a string.
private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
    // web page content.
    int len = 500;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
        return contentAsString;

    // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
    // finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        } 
    }
}
```

**Source:** [Connecting to the Network](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)